# Quickly generating ViewModel properties in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

after reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), a have the following code in my `PersonViewModel` class:

```
public Jurisdiction CountryResidence
{
    get
    {
        return Model.CountryResidence;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Model.CountryResidence == value)
            return;
        else
        {
            Model.CountryResidence = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CountryResidence");
        }
    }
}

public Jurisdiction CountryBirth
{
    get
    {
        return Model.CountryBirth;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Model.CountryBirth == value)
            return;
        else
        {
            Model.CountryBirth = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CountryBirth");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have `CountryDomiciled`, `CountryPassport` and `LegalJurisdiction`, all with the same format. Similarly, I have lots of `String` properties, all of which share their format.

This results in lots of samey code! However, I can't work out how to make this more concise.

Is there a better way to generate these properties that keeps them strongly typed?

Comment: +1 for coining the phrase "samey code"!  I'm going to have to use that one.

Comment: If you are using C# 5, you can get rid of some boilerplate code with new attributes. See here: http://bhrnjica.net/2012/03/18/new-feature-in-c-5-0-callermembername/

Comment: @Vlad Thanks, this seems neat. In this case though all c#5 gives me is ability to remove the string from `OnPropertyChanged`, right?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist

Comment: Vlad's link and GazTheDestroyer's duplicate question link are the best answers here, I think.

Comment: @Oliver: have you read my answer?  It generates the code for you at compile time, so what's in your file is much more lightweight (even if your generated code is the same).

Comment: @Oliver: and you can move `OnPropertyChanged` implementation to a common superclass. :) So your ViewModels will have less code. Edit: oh, you are doing it already.

Comment: @DanPuzey thanks for your answer Dan, but I'm going to go with a combination of code snippets and the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist - I like to have more control over what my code is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** NotifyPropertyWeaver is deprecated and continues its life as [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/blob/master/README.md). This is an absolute super cool way to solves this issue. It is a compile time only solution.

Here's something that will save you code and trouble: [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver)

Using the above, you can implement your properties without any `INotifyPropertyChanged` related code, and a build step will handle the wiring up for you.

It's a simple project include (also available via Nuget) that will automatically inject the `OnPropertyChanged` callbacks into the properties of any class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  It does it at compile time (so no runtime hit) and your code can just have auto-implemented properties (except in your case, where you're using a separate backing object).

It even includes the value equality check, so it covers the full logic.  I haven't tested it with manually-implemented properties, but worth checking out.

**EDIT:** I have tested it now, and it works fine: a manually implemented property will "just work."

Comment: Author commented this to my answer: "However, I'd prefer a way that keeps the shared functionality in one place, if this is possible, rather than cloning it for each property". How does your answer solves this need? I won't vote down your post though.

Comment: @EvAlex - the requirement to "keep it in one place" is to lower the maintenance cost, as it is with all code. But with an AOP approach there will be no code that must be maintained by the developer. How the AOP injects the necessary code is of no consequence in this regard.

Answer (score 11):

I use snippet for Visual Studio, which generates property with backing storage and event raising for me. Simply create xml file with name `propchanged` (or other name, if you wish) and following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>propchanged</Title>
      <Shortcut>propchanged</Shortcut>
      <Description>Code snippet for property (with call to OnPropertyChanged) and backing field</Description>
      <Author>lazyberezovsky</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>type</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
          <Default>string</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>property</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
          <Default>MyProperty</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>field</ID>
          <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
          <Default>myVar</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp">
        <![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;

    public $type$ $property$
    {
        get { return $field$;}
        set 
    {
       if ($field$ == value)
          return;

       $field$ = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("$property$");
    }
    }
    $end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

And put it to folder `C:\Users\YourName\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets\`.

Next, I inherit my ViewModels from some base ViewModel, which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` inteface and provides protected method `OnPropertyChanged` for generating `PropertyChanged' event.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Now when you type `propchanged` in Visual Studio, it will ask you for property type and name, and generate code for you.

```
public class PersonViewModel : ViewModel
{
    // type here 'propchanged' (or other shortcut assigned for snippet)
}
```

UPDATE:

Another option is generating code by AOP framework like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). In this case code will be generated and added during compilation (thus your classes will stay clean). [Here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/notifypropertychanged) is example of implementing INotifyProperty changed via PostSharp attributes:

```
[Notify]
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public Jurisdiction CountryResidence { get; set; }
    public Jurisdiction CountryBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really what you're looking for, but as an aside you can save two lines per property by reversing your logic test:

```
public Jurisdiction CountryResidence
{
    get
    {
        return Model.CountryResidence;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Model.CountryResidence != value)
        {
            Model.CountryResidence = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CountryResidence");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would +1 this, but it doesn't actually answer the question so am not going to. It would be better as a comment.

Comment: Agree, never intended it as a full answer. Have upvoted Dan's to make it top.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any built-in way, but you could record a Macro that will generate the code for you. I find the easiest way to do that is to just start recording a macro, then create whatever you want using the keyboard only (you can find a list of handy keyboard shortcuts [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259912%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) )

For example, I have one that generates the public version of a property, so all I have to type is `private string _someValue;` and hit my macro, and it will generate the public property along with the property change notification.

That said, keep in mind that it's perfectly valid in MVVM to expose the entire Model to the View for the sake of simplicity and convenience. So instead of exposing each of the Model's properties separately, you would simply create a single property for your Model object.

```
public Model SomeModel
{
    get
    {
        return Model;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Model == value)
            return;
        else
        {
            Model= value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("SomeModel");
        }
    }
}
```

And bind to the model's properties like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeModel.SomeProperty}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a "strong-typed" reference to the property name (which is required to enable refactoring),
you can use expressions. Put the following method, perhaps in a base class for your viewmodels:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler == null) return;

    var propertyName = NotifyPropertyChangedHelper.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(property);
    handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In your viewmodels, you'll then be able to do the following:

```
public Jurisdiction CountryResidence
{
    get { return Model.CountryResidence; }
    set 
    {         
        if (Model.CountryResidence == value)
            return;

        Model.CountryResidence = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => CountryResidence);
    }
}
```

Now, refactoring property names are automatically picked up since the reference is against the actual property.

This solves the pain point of hardcoding property names, though it still requires the 4-5 lines of boilerplate code. Aspect-oriented approaches like [notifypropertyweaver](http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/) and [PostSharp](http://ruskin-dantra.blogspot.com/2009/03/inotifypropertychanged-made-easier.html) really removes *all* manual coding in the viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried using Visual Studio code snippets such as `prop` or `propfull`? Just type it and press Tab key twice. Problem is `propfull` snippet doesn't raise **PropertyChanged** event.

But actually there should be third party snippets for such task. Here's what I found: [property snippet with INPC](http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/node/31)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen these before - they seem really neat. However, I'd prefer a way that keeps the shared functionality in one place, if this is possible, rather than cloning it for each property.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the question, since you still have to duplicate the code.

Comment: @Dan Puzey There was not a thing about code duplication in the question. "Is there a better way to generate these properties that keeps them strongly typed?". I answered: "There is: code snippets".