# Minimizing WPF boilerplate code on bound properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Consider a WPF dialogue with lots of input fields, which are bound to properties in a view-model. E.g.

```
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}">
...

public string FirstName {
  get { return mFirstName; }
  set {
    if (mFirstName == value) return;
    mFirstName = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
  }
}
```

As there are tens of fields like this, I would like to minimize the boilerplate C# code to be written. What options do I have?

Comment: Passing the name isn't needed, use void OnPropertyChanged  ( [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null ). Imo there are frameworks which solve the rest of the boilerplate with attributes but it's been a while ago I looked into to it. Another option is having something like a Dictionary<string, object> wrapper with generic code for getting/setting any value (also with the CallerMemberName trick) and raising the event. Then you just have for example `get{ return props.Get<int>() }` and `set{ props.Set(value); }`

Comment: You can also use proper tools, like Resharper, which can generate that boilerplate code for you (or at least make it much easier).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of using a base class, consider inheriting view model objects from something like this:

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;

        // ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void OnPropertiesChanged(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        foreach (string propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage, showing that the boilerplate is greatly reduced:

```
public sealed class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        private set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
    }
}
```

(If you can't use a base class (e.g., you already have one or are using properties on framework elements), you still have the option of adding similar support directly in the class in question.)

Comment: Not bad, but no need to be an abstract class.

Comment: No, it doesn't _need_ to be. But instantiating an instance of `BindableBase` is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can make your code a little easier to transform into a snippet.

```
if (mFirstName != value) {
    mFirstName = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
}
```

If just the time taken to write it is a pain, and you're using WPF a lot, snippets may also be of use. I know in Sublime Text, VS Code, and Visual Studio, Snippets can be invaluable. Otherwise,  I think it's as bare bones as you can get, unless there's something I am not seeing

Answer (score 0):

First, as I guess you already use Microsoft.Prism, you can drop the string and profit from [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) behind the scenes for you, so that your code would look like this:

```
public string FirstName {
  get { return mFirstName; }
  set {
    if (mFirstName == value) return;
    mFirstName = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

This is also equivalent to c# 6.0 [`nameof(FirstName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator.

Second, you can dig into [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and abstract the boilerplate to an attribute. One of the AOP frameworks that deals with this is [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/features) and using it your code could look like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Though it's not free, and [AOP has it's drawbacks](https://pp.ipd.kit.edu/uploads/publikationen/constantinides04eiwas.pdf) (thanks Evk).

Similar questions have been asked [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174539/quickly-generating-viewmodel-properties-in-wpf),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051362/a-better-way-to-write-mvvm-boilerplate-code), and there does not seem to be optimal answer right now sadly, as it's everyones pain.

Comment: AOP tools (at least in .NET) usually do not use reflection - they rewrite your assembly IL code directly (so really modifying your methods\classes and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I use Fody to inject property changed code at compile time. Your class gets an [ImplementPropertyChanged] attribute, then your { get; set; } properties become notifying properties in the compiled code.

https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged